# Write an R function which takes two words as arguments/inputs

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

I would like to write an R function which takes two words as arguments/inputs and returns “Equal Length” if the number of characters are equal in two words and “Not Equal Length” otherwise. Suppose the name of the function is compare. I would like it to work as below

```
compare("EPS568","Summer")
Equal Length
compare("EPS568","SummerA")
Not Equal Length
```

I have started with -

```
compares <- function(A,B) {
if (str_length(A) == str_length(B))
return("Equal Length")
}
```

I am learning R and any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You actually need to think about what you mean by "equal length" Do you mean in memory, in counted characters, or in screen width? Luckily the very same function deals with all three, you just need to change one argument!!

```
compares <- function(A,B) {
# use type="chars" for the number of human readible characters
# use type="bytes" for the storage size of the characters
# use type="width" for the size of the string in monospace font
if (nchar(A, type="chars") == nchar(B,type="chars")) {
    return("Equal Length")
} else {
    return ("Not Equal Length")
}}


> A="this string"
> B="that string"
> compares(A,B)
[1] "Equal Length"
> B="thatt string"
> compares(A,B)
[1] "Not Equal Length"
```

Comment: great. why not add `type="chars'` in the functions parameters?

Comment: You certainly can do that. If you're learning R, that's an easy modification you can make yourself and see what's required to implement it!

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Use `nchar` instead of `str_length`. See `?nchar`.

Comment: Changing `nchar` to `str_length`, OP will still have the same problem (no `else`). And why switch?

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the else branch.
If this is the case, get a look at:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-if133else-statements-in-r.html

It's for real beginner, but it' a starting point ;)

Answer (score 0):

You've given instructions for what should happen if the string lengths *are* equal, now you need to say what should happen otherwise:

```
compares <- function(A,B) {
  if (str_length(A) == str_length(B)) {
    return("Equal Length")
  }
  return("Not Equal Length")
}
```

You could put an `else` on the same line as the if statement's end bracket (`}`), but a function will stop running code as soon as it hits the first `return`, so it's not necessary here.